# Assigning role command wont work with roles with more than one word

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

so this works to add roles to other users, but if the role has two words it wont work

```
                {
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"User already has this role");
                }

                else
                {

                    Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Mention == "RoleName");
                    await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);

                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} has been assigned {role}");
                }
```

Comment: Which part does not work when role has multiple words? In any case, you should not be comparing the role mention (`x.Mention`). You'd either compare the role name or the role id.

Answer (score 0):

`Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Mention == "RoleName")`

First of all, you probably forgot to assign `role` to the return result of the operation. 
(Or you didn't copy-paste that part properly.)

It should be

```
role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Mention == "RoleName")
```

You were trying to compare the role's name against the [role's mentioned string](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketRole.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketRole_Mention).
You should compare against the role's [`Name`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketRole.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketRole_Name) property instead, like so:

```
role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "RoleName");
```

*Alternatively*, you could compare against the role's ID too, like so:

```
role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == roleID);
```

which you can further simply by using the [`GetRole(Id)`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketGuild_GetRole_System_UInt64_) function from the `Guild`, like so:

```
role = Context.Guild.GetRole(roleId);
```

Comment: I figured it out I just needed to add the remainder to my task